# Parsing JSON data to Map markers, all markers showing the same info, how can I fix this?

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, android-asynctask

need a bit of help with this one.

I have JSON of a some shops and the shops information, like their names, ids and locations. I parsed it into an ArrayList.

Through an AsyncTask I plotted them on a map. Currently, that's 4 shops. I Overrided the marker onClick to show the data the way I wanted. The problem I'm having is that although the markers are in the correct places based on the longitude and latitude, the other information is not.

When I click on a marker, the same shop name is listed on all of them. It's only showing the last shop in my JSON. All the data is coming from the last shop in my JSON. Here is my onPostExecute() code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ShopArray> shopArray) {
    super.onPostExecute(shopArray);

    for (ShopArray shopArrayOb : shopArray) {
        double lat = shopArrayOb.geo_lat;
        double lng = shopArrayOb.geo_lng;

        final String barName = shopArrayOb.bar_name;

        LatLng shopLocations = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(shopLocations)
            gMap.addMarker(marker);

        gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                testText.setText(barName);

                return false;
            }

        });
    }
```

I don't really know how to fix this. I just want it to show the correct names for the markers, amongst other data. It keeps showing data from the last shop in my JSON and nothing else. If you need to see more of my code then let me know and I will update my post.

I would really appreciate some help on this, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I've just tested with the default marker onClick. (.title and .snippet) and it worked! It's showing the correct info!
Is there a way to get a custom onClick then? Looks like setOnMarkerListener is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're calling `setOnMarkerClickListener()` on the SAME `gMap` object multiple times. In this way it's not strange that the last call will take effect, and the last shop's info will be used. You should set `OnMarkerClickListener` only once. Of course, then you have to identify your markers in its `onMarkerClick()` method to decide which shop was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, if I call gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener, do you think that will fix this? I only have one marker to identify (marker) I assume it was already the one being called. Just trying to figure out my next step now, because I still want a custom output when a marker is clicked.

Comment: No. You have 4 markers on the map, one for each coffee shop. But you have only one OnMarkerClickListener which passes you a marker which was clicked (look at the parameter).
And here you have to detect which coffee shop was clicked.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a way to do that so that my code does not have to be updated everytime I add new shops in my JSON on the server? You make it sound like that I would have to call each marker individually, even when I add another 20 or 30.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your all markers in HashMap:

```
//somewhere befor async task    
HashMap<LatLng, String> map = new HashMap<LatLng, String>();
```

Then add markers to it:

```
//in your post execute
map.put(shopLocations, barName);
```

Then in your listener:

```
gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            testText.setText(map.get(marker.getPosition()));

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: That still shows me the last shop in the list. I've called the HashMap at the very start of my class (a fragment) and the map.put() bit just after I set the marker and just before the onClick.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit further? I feel like it's the correct route to go down but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, this's the correct route. It shows the last marker because of what I've already told you: move the gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener() call off the for(){} block! Don't change the OnMarkerClickListener of the map every time you add a new marker! Call it only once at the end of your code!

Comment: Do not use `LatLng` as key. There is [a bug in the library](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5353), that can cause it not to work properly.

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem I've moved my setOnMarkerClickListener() to outside of the for loop, it's still in my onPostExecute(). Using the HashMap I'm still getting the last shops info so it must be calling the onClick more than once. I would really appreciate any advice you might have. Thanks for helping btw. I'm still using LatLng as a key because the data is all based on location.  Wouldn't know what to do if I couldn't use that.

Comment: Can you assure tha HashMap contains the correct keys and values? (Check with debugger, or print to a log to assure.)

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem I set up a few logs. Within the for loop it pulls every shop name 3 times each. Once it gets to the onClick it only shows the last one. I guess I need to control the for loop somehow